# Predicting $A_n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$$A_2=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$A_3=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$A_4=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

so I found that

$$
det(A_2)=-1\\ det(A_3)=0det(A_2)+2 \\ det(A_4) = 0det(A_3)-3det(A_2)-6
$$

Did I do the calculations wrong, I don't think so. I'm using cofactors in order to find the determinants but I couldn't find any. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Do you want a formula for the determinant of $A_n$?

Comment: Yes I'm looking for a formula for $det(A_n)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It suffices to note that $A_n+I$ is a rank $1$ matrix with eigenvalues $0$ ($n-1$ times) and $n$ (one time). It follows that $A_n$ has eigenvalue $-1$ $(n-1)$ times and eigenvalue $(n-1)$ $1$ time.

Thus, $\det(A_n)=(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)$.

Comment: I think you mean eigenvalue $n-1$ one time and not $n$ times.

Comment: Fixed it, thanks.